# Postgresql взять подстроку по совпадению LIKE

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Существует ли способ сразу из Postgresql достать подстроку, найденную с помощью LIKE?
Есть таблица, в одном из столбцов храниться текст комментариев типа text. Я с помощью запроса нахожу конкретный или конкретные комментарии, используя LIKE (%пример%). Мне надо достать не полные комментарии а только их часть, например, такого типа (20символов - %пример% - 20символов). Т.е. искомый LIKE и по 20 символов до и после него.

Comment: вот прямо с помощью like нельзя, а с помощью регулярного выражения можно достать функцией regexp_matches https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/functions-matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока нашел такой вариант, может кто подскажет лучше вариант

```
SELECT
       SUBSTR(
         ems.main_search,
         (STRPOS(ems.main_search, 'ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ') - 20),
         (STRPOS(ems.main_search, 'ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ') + LENGHT('ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ') + 20))
FROM estimation_main_search ems
WHERE ems.main_search LIKE '%ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ%';
```